# Github "Product v2" not working with Discord Webhooks

Tags: github, discord, webhooks

I've been trying to connect GitHub with my Discord Server, where for any event I get notified in a specific channel. Everything seems to be going through, except "Project v2" and "Project Items v2". From GitHub's side I get a 204 status code, so it seems okay, but on my Discord channel, I don't get any form of notification.

I read that there might be trouble with Discord itself not parsing these payloads correctly, but is there any way to fix this, without using any third-party services.

I tried changing the Content Type, I even tried creating a separate webhook just for the project board changes, but I still don't get any notifications about it.